# How to remove weird lines from model

Tags: blender, modeling

After I deleted unnecessary edges I got these weird lines. So, how do I remove them? 
It's not the first time I get these lines on my models, but I can't find any questions asking to solve this.
[image]

Comment: An n-gon is a face that has more than four sides, I expect that is what you have after you deleted the extra edges. When an n-gon gets triangulated to be drawn, you can sometimes get odd shading like that if the vertices making the n-gon do not make a flat surface. I expect you will need to add some of the edges back in.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up some loop cuts (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) on that mesh, or try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, this will triangulate the mesh, sometimes this can help in these kind of situation. <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> de-triangulates to make quads if you need it to make N-Gons.